# Contact form not parsing errors or success messages

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Creating a small contact type form for a project where people can register interest in the site, giving a few details about themselves. So I decided to follow this tutorial and modify it to suit my needs : http://bit.ly/13zQ7em

I have modified the PHP and jQuery in order to get the email to send, which it now does however I can't figure out why the jQuery is not firing the success message when it does so, or displaying any errors when I type some in.

As far as I can see, everything should be firing through ok, but I've obviously missed something and I can't figure out what. So any help would be greatly appreciated!

Current live form : http://bit.ly/12yS1eh

HTML :

```
<div id="interested">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>INTERESTED?</h2>
            <p>If you would like to stay up to date with upcoming content, release dates and chances to win signed prints of the photos, 
            just fill in your details below.</p>
        <div id="thanks"></div>
        <form action="javascript:alert('success!');" id="interestForm">
                <div id="formLeft">
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="" placeholder="First name" />
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="email@email.com" />
                </div>

                <div id="formMiddle">
                        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="" placeholder="Last name" />
                        <input type="text" id="country" name="country" value="" placeholder="Your country" />
                </div>

                <div id="formRight">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" />
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#interestForm").submit(function(){

var str = $(this).serialize();

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "contact_form/contact.php",
   data: str,
   success: function(msg){

$("#thanks").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){

if(msg == 'OK') // If the email is sent show 'Thank You' message and hide the form
{
result = '<div class="notification_ok">Thanks for registering your interest, we\'ll be in contact soon with more information about the iBook.</div>';
$("#interestForm").hide();
}
else
{
result = msg;
}

$(this).hide();
$(this).html(result).slideDown("slow");

$(this).html(result);

});

}

 });

return false;

});

});
```

PHP:

```
    <?php

include 'config.php';
    error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
    {
        include 'functions.php';
        $firstName = stripslashes($_POST['firstName']);
        $lastName = stripslashes($_POST['lastName']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $country = stripslashes($_POST['country']);

        $message = "";
        $message .= "First Name: ";
        $message .= $firstName;
        $message .= "\n";
        $message .= "Last Name: ";
        $message .= $lastName;
        $message .= "\n";
        $message .= "Email: ";
        $message .= $email;
        $message .= "\n";
        $message .= "Country ";
        $message .= $country;


        $error = '';

// Check firstName
if(!$firstName)
    {
        $error .= 'You forgot to enter your first name.<br />';
    }

// Check lastName
if(!$lastName)
    {
        $error .= 'You forgot to enter your last name.<br />';
    }

// Check country
if(!$country)
    {
        $error .= 'You forgot to enter your country.<br />';
    }

// Check email
if(!$email)
    {
        $error .= 'You forgot to enter your e-mail id.<br />';
    }
if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
    {
        $error .= 'Invalid E-mail id !!!<br />';
    }
if(!$error)
    {
        $subject = 'Hi, '.$firstName. '  ' .$lastName. '  is interested in Ireland - In a new light';
        $mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
            "From: ".$firstName." ".$lastName." <".$email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
            ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
if($mail)
    {
        echo 'OK';
    }
}
else
    {
        echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching the `.ajaxComplete()` handler wrong.

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached
>   to document.

You may also want to use `jQuery 1.9` instead of `2.0` (not supported in IE > 9)

You can remove the handler (since you're not really using it much anyway)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#interestForm").submit(function() {
                    var str = $(this).serialize();
                    var thx = $("#thanks");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "contact_form/contact.php",
                        data: str,
                        success: function(msg) {

                                if (msg == 'OK') // If the email is sent show 'Thank You' message and hide the form
                                {
                                    result = '<div class="notification_ok">Thanks for registering your interest, we\'ll be in contact soon with more information about the iBook.</div>';
                                    $("#interestForm").hide();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    result = msg;
                                }
                                thx.hide();
                                thx.html(result).slideDown("slow");

                                //thx.html(result); <-- you don't need to put it 2 times
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Or use `$(document).ajaxComplete();` somewhere else but not in `success: function() {} ..`

Comment: works like a charm amigo, really appreciate the help and knowledge, I didn't realise .ajaxComplete() could only be attached to to document!

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of your javascript files don't load:

- js/greensock/TweenMax.min.js
- js/jquery.superscrollorama.js
- js/smoothscroll.js
- js/jquery.cycle2.js
- js/modernizr-1.7.min.js

Might that be something to do with it?

Perhaps not because they aren't really validation scripts... but it's worth fixing to discount it as a potential issue. Additionally one of your CSS files doesn't load either

- css/mob_global.css

Comment: sorry, should have taken that out of the version I uploaded there (its a snippet of the whole site) - now fixed. Unfortunately though this doesn't fix anything, the code just bypasses through them if they aren't there.